# Can't run unit test using JRuby, no such file to load -- rubygems

Tags: error-handling, rubygems, load, jruby, watir

When running same test using ruby only I get success. When trying to run same test from java using JRuby it doesn't find the require files such as "watir-webdriver", "rubygems" etc.

The Ruby file:

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"

puts "Hello!!! test finished"
```

Error trace:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- rubygems
  require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054
   (root) at /home/Oras/workspace/OptifyTestSuiteRuby/automation-watir/tes.rb:2
Exception in thread "main" org.jruby.embed.EvalFailedException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- rubygems
    at org.jruby.embed.internal.EmbedEvalUnitImpl.run(EmbedEvalUnitImpl.java:133)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runUnit(ScriptingContainer.java:1264)
    at org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer.runScriptlet(ScriptingContainer.java:1309)
    at OptifyTest.com.Main.<init>(Main.java:18)
    at OptifyTest.com.Main.main(Main.java:22)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- rubygems
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054)
    at RUBY.(root)(/home/Oras/workspace/OptifyTestSuiteRuby/automation-watir/tes.rb:2)
```

The Java file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  

import org.jruby.embed.PathType;
import org.jruby.embed.ScriptingContainer;

public class Main {
private final static String jrubyhome = "/home/Oras/workspace/OptifyTestSuiteRuby/automation-  watir";
private final String filename = jrubyhome + "/tes.rb";

private Main() {
    ScriptingContainer container = new ScriptingContainer();
    List<String> loadPaths = new ArrayList();
    loadPaths.add(jrubyhome);
    container.setLoadPaths(loadPaths);
    container.runScriptlet(PathType.ABSOLUTE, filename);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
}
}
```

Comment: I tried to play a little bit with the loadPath.add, Maybe I haven't added the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succeed including rubygems by downloaded manually and include thos path:
loadPaths.add("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems");
loadPaths.add("/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.4/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rubygems-update-2.0.3/lib/");

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error using JRuby installed via RVM.

JRuby version:

```
$ jruby -v
jruby 1.7.4 (1.9.3p392) [snip]
```

The following showed the correct gem list (after executing bundle)

```
$ jruby -Xdebug.scriptResolution=true -S gem list
```

Compiled my app using:

```
$ jrubyc main.rb
```

When I executed I had to add the classpath for jruby-complete jar, found here:
http://repository.codehaus.org/org/jruby/jruby-complete/1.7.4/

```
$ java -cp .:./jruby-complete-1.7.4.jar main
```